# Can't seem to set AcceptPathInfo in Apache

Tags: php5, apache-2.4

I'm trying to migrate an ExpressionEngine site onto a new server and seem to have run into a roadblock. For the desired functionality, EE requires the `AcceptPathInfo` directive to be turned on, and for the life of me, I can't seem to get Apache to cooperate.

The server is running Fedora Core 18, Apache 2.4.3 with the PHP 5.4.11 Apache Module.

I've tried setting the following in my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/mysite/public_html
        ServerName mysite.com
        <Directory /home/mysite/public_html/>
                AcceptPathInfo On
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but when I debug using `phpinfo()`, it still doesn't show path_info, orig_path_info or orig_path_info_translated (which I believe are produced as a result of the AcceptPathInfo directive being turned on).

I've also tried simply setting the directive `AcceptPathInfo` On in my .htaccess file, but still to no avail.

I've been going through the settings between my Dev and Live environments, and it seems that the Dev server is running PHP using FastCGI and is using cgi.fix_pathinfo.

Normally, I'm fairly confident in tinkering with my httpd.conf and php.ini, but at this point, I'm way further down the rabbit hole than I'm comfortable with. What am I missing here?

Comment: Same issue over here (Kubuntu 15.04 + Apache 2.4) while trying to install Moodle 2.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn on `AcceptPathInfo` in Apache, (p.ex Moodle 2.9) in you will need to change httpd.conf like:

For Apache versions earlier than 2.4:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName moodleback.local
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/moodle"
    AcceptPathInfo On
    <Directory /usr/local/www/moodle>
      AllowOverride None
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For Apache version 2.4.x or above:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName moodleback.local
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/moodle"
    AcceptPathInfo On
    <Directory /usr/local/www/moodle/>
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```